# Parsing a string to remove spaces

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have this problem where I have to remove spaces from the string

And I want to use `parseString`

Is it okay to use it?

Example is

```
String one = "ba t , ca t , ra t";
//output should be bat,cat,rat
```

Comment: What about using `one.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Answer (score 4):

You can either do

```
one.replaceAll(" ","");
```

**OR**

```
one.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

Both works!